# How do I craft a URL to open/display a google sheet filtered by a certain parameter?

Tags: google-sheets, url

Sample Google Sheet:

| NAME | AGE | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Robert | 22 | Red |
| John | 21 | Blue |
| Ann | 20 | Purple |
| John | 21 | Green |

Call with URL: `http://{URL to Google Sheet above}/parameters`

What parameters should I use here to filter by `NAME = John` and get the result below?

Result: Google sheet is open, but filtered as follows:

| NAME | AGE | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 21 | Blue |
| John | 21 | Green |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

There is no [URL parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to specify a key value such as `John` to filter by, but you can specify a [filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to open with the `fvid` parameter, and use the parameter to open a specific filter view that only shows rows with `John` in a certain column.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

If you just want to get the raw data instead of opening an editable spreadsheet, you can use a [query string](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#setting-the-query-in-the-data-source-url) like this:

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/gviz/tq?tq=select B where A contains "bird"&sheet=Sheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/gviz/tq?tq=select%20B%20where%20A%20contains%20%22bird%22&sheet=Sheet2)